# Does the expression $x^4 +y^4$ take on all values in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

> As the title asks: does there exist $N$ such that, for any prime $p$ larger than $N$, the expression $x^4 +y^4$ takes on all values in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

I have been thinking about this problem for days, but I failed to solve it. Does anyone know whether this is true, or does anyone know any partial results about it?

Partial results:
If $p=4k+3$, it easily works
if $p=4k+1$, if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, and $A_i = \left\{ g^k : k \equiv i \pmod{4} \right\}$, then at least three of $A_i (i=0,1,2,3)$ must be expressed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're using $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to denote the ring of $p$-adics or for $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @YCor I'm not sure that matters, in the light of Hensel's lemma...by which I suspect that if the statement holds for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then it holds for $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk sure but it would matter in the way to formulate an answer.

Comment: Ok, I get you now :-)

Comment: Actually it is quite important whether $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the $p$-adic integers or the finite field. In the latter case the answer is yes, but not in the former case. The problem is that $x^4 + y^4 = p$ has a solution in the $p$-adics if and only if $p$ is split in the $8$th cyclotomic field (i.e. $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$). The easiest way I know how to prove it over a finite field is via the Hasse-Weil theorem, but probably there is an elementary approach.

Comment: @Daniel ah i forgot that case, very silly of me, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: So are you clarifying that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ does indeed denote the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. What I intended was $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}$ , not p-adic integers

Comment: @Daniel could you explain why the answer is yes in that case please?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353024/x4-y4-mod-p).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

emtom has found the right reference, but there is a more explicit result in that book (Ireland and Rosen, *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*). In fact, Theorem 5 of Chapter 8 (on page 103) directly implies that the number $N = N_{p,\alpha}$ of solutions to $x^4+y^4=\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies the inequality
$$
\left| N - p \right| \leq M_0 + M_1 p^{1/2}
$$
for some $M_0$ and $M_1$ that are described explicitly in the statement of the theorem (and from that description it easily follows they can be bounded in a way that is independent of $p$ or $\alpha$).

It then automatically follows that for sufficiently large $p$, we will have $N_{p,\alpha}>0$ for all $\alpha$. In other words, for sufficiently large $p$, the expression $x^4+y^4$ assumes all values of $\mathbb{F}_p$ as $x$ and $y$ run through $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Of course, this is no better (and possibly slightly worse) than what you get from the Hasse-Weil bound which Dan Loughran referred to, but at least this reference has the virtue of providing a completely elementary proof.

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on a comment, the curve $X^4+Y^4=aZ^4$ (for $a\ne0$) has genus $3$. So the Hasse-Weil bound says
$$ N_p(a) := \#\bigl\{ [X,Y,Z]\in\mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_p) : X^4+Y^4=aZ^4 \bigr\} $$
satisfies
$$ \bigl| N_p(a) - p - 1 \bigr| \le 2g\sqrt{p} = 6\sqrt{p}. $$
Thus
$$ N_p(a) \ge p + 1 - 6\sqrt{p}. $$
There are at most $4$ points with $Z=0$, so
$$
\#\bigl\{ (X,Y) \in\mathbb A^2(\mathbb F_p) : X^4+Y^4=a \bigr\} \ge p-3-6\sqrt{p}.
$$
So you'll always have a solution provided $p\ge3+6\sqrt{p}$, which means that there is always a solution provided $p\ge43$.

Comment: By adding a numerical computation, it seems to hold for all $p \geq 31$. For $p=29$, we get e.g. that there are no $x,y \in \mathbb{F}_{29}$ such that $x^4+y^4=4$.

Comment: @RP That makes sense, I took the worst possible case that there are 4 $\mathbb F_p$ rational points at infinity, but for many values of $p$, there will be less. It ultimately depends on whether $-1$ is a square root, and whether it is a fourth root.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly an answer, but in exercise $18$ in page $106$ of Ireland and Rosen's A Classical Introduction to Modern Number theory it states: Let $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ and let $p=A^2+B^2$ where we fix $A$ by requiring that $A\equiv 1\mod 4$. Then $N=\#\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{F}_p^2\mid x^4+y^4=1\}$ satisfies $N=p-3-6A$ if $p\equiv1\mod 8$ and $N=p+1+2A$ if $p\equiv5\mod 8$.